# Copy Console Windows And Paste In NotePad

Tags: windows-xp, console

How to copy the content inside the cmd windows, and paste it in NotePad?

I tried to select "Mark", and highlight the console area, and try to press ctrl+v on a notepad, but it works sometimes and doesn't work other times.

Comment: This gets me every so often & I've been using Windows for more than 15 years! Yes, it's been like this since Windows 3.1 (& probably earlier)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you highlight it to send it to the clipboard.

If you want to send the entire output of a command to a text file, you can simply use a chevron.

example:

```
dir > C:\output.txt
```

and to append to a text file, 2 chevrons:

```
dir >> C:\output.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Once you've `Mark`ed, you have to hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to copy it :)

You may be interested in software such as [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), which provides a wrapper around the shell, which among other things allows for copying in the style of *every other application ever*.

Answer (score 3):

I use the right mouse button to copy and paste in the command window.

Works much nicer.

So mark your selection with the mouse, press the right mouse button to copy it to the clipboard.

And if you want to paste something from your clipboard, use the right mouse button again.

(this is however when the quick edit mode is enabled)

Comment: This only works when "QuickEdit Mode" is enabled in the console window properties.

Comment: correct, I forgot I enable this by default.

Answer (score 1):

Do a right-click into the window after making the selection. The selection box will disappear and the text will be in the clipboard.
If you do a left-click instead, it will start a new selection and copy nothing.